# Methods to avoid multiple return statements

Tags: c++, return

My efforts to find ways to avoid multiple return statements, so that cleanup of resources doesn't get duplicated, has led me find the following ways:

1. Using MACRO, perform clean up if error is not OK.

   ```
   #define EXE(x) if (OK != (err = x)) goto cleanup;

   ErrorCode func ()
   {
      ErrorCode err = OK;

      EXE (fn1());
      EXE (fn2());

   cleanup:
      // do cleanup of resources
      return err;
   }
   ```
2. Using do...while() break when error occurs

   ```
   ErrorCode func ()
   {
       ErrorCode err = OK;
       do
       {
           err = fn1();
           if (err != OK) break;

           err = fn2();
           if (err != OK) break;

       } while (false);

       // do cleanup of resources
       return err;
   }
   ```

Both the ways allow cleanup of resources at one place(immediately above the return statement) and improves readability. Is there any other way to avoid multiple returns?

Comment: This looks more like C than C++. Usually destructors are used to "clean things up", so having multiple returns really isn't a problem.

Comment: Exactly, in C++, that `//do clean up` section normally just disappears. Anyway, you've got something with the macro approach - it's essentially Haskell's do notation. That said, I don't recommend it with a macro in C++.

Comment: A vector of functions, and execute them in a loop.

Comment: Why are you making Herculean efforts to avoid having more than one return statement?

Comment: This business of avoiding multiple return statements is perpetrated only in academia. It derives from the one-entry one-exit principle. It is refutable thus: the compiler transforms multiple return statements into a single return statement anyway (see the assembly code): *ergo* the original code with multiple return statements is formally equivalent to a single return statement; *ergo* there can be no possible objection to multiple return statements. What *is* objectionable here is the `goto` statements. I finally stopped using them completely in 1997 with Java and I have never missed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to resort to `goto` to clean things up in C++. All objects that have been constructed in automatic scope will be destructed. They must be responsible for cleaning up.

That said, you can use a macro to simplify writing of error checking code.

```
#define CHECK_ERROR(x) if (OK != x) return x;

ErrorCode func ()
{
   ErrorCode err = OK;

   err = fn1();
   CHECK_ERROR(err);

   err = fn2();
   CHECK_ERROR(err);

   return err;
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Use a helper class to call `CloseHandle`.

```
struct HandlerMinder
{
   HandleMinder(ErrorCode& err, HANDLE hObject) :
      err_(err), hObject_(hObject) {}

   ~HandleMinder()
   {
      // Adapt the logic to suit your needs.
      if ( err_ != OK )
      {
         CloseHandle(hObject_);
      }
   }

   ErrorCode& err_;
   HANDLE hObject_;
};

ErrorCode func ()
{
   ErrorCode err = OK;
   HANDLE object = <some handle>;
   HandleMinder m(err, object);

   err = fn1();
   CHECK_ERROR(err);

   err = fn2();
   CHECK_ERROR(err);

   return err;
}
```

Comment: What if function got to resource cleanup (memory/handles/..) that needn't fit to be a member var?

Comment: Show what have you in mind. In general, that is usually not a problem.

Comment: Memory allocation can be dealt using smart pointers, but what can be done with others like "CloseHandle" for windows objects or kind of Release method that appear in COM, which needn't have to be made a member just for de-allocation in destructor?

Comment: COM has [CComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) for this. In general, there is usually a RAII wrapper for pretty much everything